# How do you change the functionality of a method from outside of the class?

Tags: java

Sorry for the confusing title, but I have no idea how to phrase this in under a sentence. What I want to do is have a menu system of "buttons" that do different things when clicked (pause, end, go to a different menu, etc). The only ways I can think of doing this are

a) Have a million subclasses, which is bad

b) Have a million if-statements, which is also bad

Ideally, I would like something where I can just declare the new instance of the class, and then add in the method at the same time, kind of like how the keyAdaptor works.

Thanks in advance!

~Tree

Comment: your question isn't clear, you want each button to do different "thing"? or one "thing" gets called by all the buttons and depending on the button to perform certain actions?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the button class and have different handlers for each button. There would be a different function for every different thing you wanted the buttons to do, but a the buttons themselves could all the be same class.

Comment: What exactly is a handler? I tried reading about it, but it seems to be some sort of file reading thing. Sorry about my lack of knowledge, I'm just getting started :)

Comment: Sorry about that stupidity, still getting used to the terminology.

Comment: Handlers define what action should be done when the user performs a certain operation. By using a single button class over and over, and assigning different handlers to the different instances of class, you're able to have the one class do multiple things. Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for a tutorial that explains handlers and how to use them fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution would be to have a single class and pass the method as a parameter, as is possible in functional programming languages. For the time being this is not possible, but look forward to Java 8's [Lambda Expressions](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335). For example, something like this will be possible:

```
public class MyButton implements ActionListener {

    private ActionListener handler;

    public MyButton(ActionListener lambda) {
        handler = lambda;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        handler(event);
    }

}
```

And you will be able to create new buttons like this:

```
MyButton but1 = new MyButton(e -> /* do something */);
MyButton but2 = new MyButton(e -> /* do something else */);
```

Similarly, it'll be possible to directly add an action listener to an existing `JButton`:

```
button.addActionListener(e -> /* do something */);
```

Another more verbose, but currently available option would be to pass the action listener as an anonymous class parameter, and override the relevant method(s), as shown in @Basilio German's answer.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble (you've already helped a lot) could I get a sample of how that would work? I'm still a bit confused as to how to get the ActionEvent to be my condition.

Comment: @Treesin I don't understand the comment; the lambda is received as a parameter and called as a normal method, there's no "condition" - you just pass the appropriate lambda for each button.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a single class with lots of different buttons, and have each button do a different thing. here is the code for a JButton to do something specific:

```
    JButton exampleButton= new JButton("Click me!");
    exampleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Do something when the button is clicked
        }
    });
```

Of course, you would call play(), stop(), or whatever you want from inside it

Comment: Would there be a way to do this, but not actually using the JButton class but rather something I made? Would I just have to implement ActionListner, pass it in as a param, and go from there? If that were possible, how would the ActionEvent be coded in?